# JQuery execute functions sequentially

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got a problem executing functions sequentially.
On my html file I've got this:

```
<body onload="start();">

    <div id="title"><div id="welcome">WELCOME</div></div>
```

Inside my JS I've got this, which should execute the background change to black, and when that ended it would make the "welcome" div appear.

```
function start(){

    $('body').css('background', 'black', function() {
        $('#welcome').fadeIn("slow");
    });

}
```

Problem is: Only the background change is being executed. I get no errors on the browser console.

Any ideas on where I might have gone wrong?

EDIT: I've got this on the `body` css so that it slowly changes from white to black

```
-webkit-transition:all 1.0s ease;
    -moz-transition:all 1.0s ease;
    transition:all 1.0s ease;
```

Comment: Why is there a function inside `.css`? I don't see it [anywhere in the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/css/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where in the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/css/) do you see that function signature? That does not exist.

```
.css( propertyName )
.css( propertyNames )
.css( propertyName, value)
.css( propertyName, function(index, value) )
.css( properties )
```

Break it up, there is no callback that executes. It is not an asynchronous step.

```
$('body').css('background', 'black');
$('#welcome').fadeIn("slow");
```

Comment: Thing is: how can I change the duration of the background change?

Comment: css() is not animate()

Answer (score 0):

Why not update each function in one line?

```
function start() { // rename this..
  $('body').css('background', 'black');
  $('#welcome').fadeIn();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.. may be helpful to you.

```
$('body').css('background', 'black');
$('#welcome').fadeIn("slow");
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery css() doesn't have a callback - I think you confuse it with "animate" which is a slow (therefore a delayed) thing to do while "css" happens immediately.

You can chain jQuery commands like this:

```
$(".stuff").css("background","black").css("color","red")
```

This can be done with anything that happens immediately.  Callbacks are for proper timing when something takes time.

Also, for css, there is another way:

```
$(".stuff").css({
    "background":"black",
    "color":"red",
});
```

But that's not very general in jQuery.  Chaining (like above) will work almost everywhere.